# On Parse.com, how can I query for User by 'child' object fields?

Tags: parse-platform

I have a simple query I'm trying to perform with Parse that for some reason is not working. I have a "User" class that contains a column pointing to a "Subscription" class. I'm trying to query/get the User that owns the Subscription, and the one thing I know is the 'specialId' field of the subscription.

[image]

**Query**-

```
curl -X GET \
Headers...
--data-urlencode 'where={"subscriptions":{"$inQuery":{"where":{"specialId":
  'e9289xc9'},"className":"Subscription"}}}
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Users
```

Anyone see what's wrong with my query? Many thanks!

Comment: any chance you can share what you used to make the diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your endpoint may just be wrong. You can use either the real name for the built-in user class at /1/classes/_Users, or you can use the helper endpoint /1/users.

Comment: Thanks Thomas- I cobbled together the REST version of my failing call- I'm actually using a NodeJS Stripe NPM and thought it would be easier to answer seeing a generic REST call. That being said, I can find users and subscriptions fine, it's just the nuance of the inQuery operator I can't quite master.